# Can't use https proxies along with reusing the same session within a script built upon asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to use `https` proxy within async requests making use of asyncio library. When it comes to use `http` proxy, there is a clear instruction [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#proxy-support) but I get stuck in case of using `https` proxy. Moreover, I would like to reuse the same session, not creating a new session every time I send a requests.

I've tried so far (`proxies used within the script are directly taken from a free proxy site, so consider them as placeholders`):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

proxies = [
    'http://89.22.210.191:41258',
    'http://91.187.75.48:39405',
    'http://103.81.104.66:34717',
    'http://124.41.213.211:41828',
    'http://93.191.100.231:3128'
]

async def get_text(url):
    global proxies,proxy_url
    while True:
        check_url = proxy_url
        proxy = f'http://{proxy_url}'
        print("trying using:",check_url)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            try:
                async with session.get(url,proxy=proxy,ssl=False) as resp:
                    return await resp.text()
            except Exception:
                if check_url == proxy_url:
                    proxy_url = proxies.pop()

async def field_info(field_link):              
    text = await get_text(field_link)          
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text,'lxml')
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        print(item.get_text(strip=True))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxy_url = proxies.pop()
    links = ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&page={}&pagesize=50".format(page) for page in range(2,5)]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.gather(*(field_info(url) for url in links)))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
    loop.close()
```

How can I use `https` proxies within the script along with reusing the same `session`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script creates dictionary `proxy_session_map`, where keys are proxies and values are sessions. That way we know for which proxy belongs which session.

If there's some error using the proxy, I add this proxy to `disabled_proxies` set so I won't use this proxy again:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from random import choice

proxies = [
    'http://89.22.210.191:41258',
    'http://91.187.75.48:39405',
    'http://103.81.104.66:34717',
    'http://124.41.213.211:41828',
    'http://93.191.100.231:3128'
]

disabled_proxies = set()

proxy_session_map = {}

async def get_text(url):
    while True:
        try:
            available_proxies = [p for p in proxies if p not in disabled_proxies]

            if available_proxies:
                proxy = choice(available_proxies)
            else:
                proxy = None

            if proxy not in proxy_session_map:
                proxy_session_map[proxy] = aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=5))

            print("trying using:",proxy)

            async with proxy_session_map[proxy].get(url,proxy=proxy,ssl=False) as resp:
                return await resp.text()

        except Exception as e:
            if proxy:
                print("error, disabling:",proxy)
                disabled_proxies.add(proxy)
            else:
                # we haven't used proxy, so return empty string
                return ''


async def field_info(field_link):
    text = await get_text(field_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text,'lxml')
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        print(item.get_text(strip=True))

async def main():
    links = ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&page={}&pagesize=50".format(page) for page in range(2,5)]
    tasks = [field_info(url) for url in links]

    await asyncio.gather(
        *tasks
    )

    # close all sessions:
    for s in proxy_session_map.values():
        await s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints (for example):

```
trying using: http://89.22.210.191:41258
trying using: http://124.41.213.211:41828
trying using: http://124.41.213.211:41828
error, disabling: http://124.41.213.211:41828
trying using: http://93.191.100.231:3128
error, disabling: http://124.41.213.211:41828
trying using: http://103.81.104.66:34717
BeautifulSoup to get image name from P class picture tag in Python
Scrape instagram public information from google cloud functions [duplicate]
Webscraping using R - the full website data is not loading
Facebook Public Data Scraping
How it is encode in javascript?

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Andrej. I'll give you any feedback once I'm done testing. I haven't come across any solution of  your's which didn't work, so your answer deserves a thumbs-up in advance.

Comment: It appears to be working correctly. So, I was on the right track with my `http` approach, right? I thought the parameters would be somewhat different when I try using `https`. Any comment of your's on this will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU Yes, you were right. As far as I remember, `aiohttp` handles `http` and `https` proxies transparently. Only thing I changed was handling of disabled proxies and how to pair proxy to `ClientSession` object. I also removed explicit using `loop.`. For this level of code it isn't necessary.